# Protect email from harvesters & spam

Tags: php, email, codeigniter, spam

Most anti-spam scripts I have seen are actually javascript scripts that obscure the email by encoding it with character entities. But I think a good bot would still find this easy to decode again?

On my website I used a separate controller that is only used to send mails. The page receives an encrypted email parameter through GET and decypts it using a specific private key. Then sets the header to: mailto: $email and redirects the user back to where he came from.

Is this an effective way to protect email links or am I overseeing something important?

```
if ($this->uri->total_segments() >= 1) {
    $email = $this->decode($this->uri->uri_string());
    if ($email) {
         header("location: mailto: " . $email);
         if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
             redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'refresh');
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you can't avoid passing the email address through GET, I think that's a fairly good effort and raises the entry barrier high enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine, and is a known technique, e.g. http://www.maxi-pedia.com/prevent+email+address+harvesting & http://csarven.ca/hiding-email-addresses#javascript.

It can still be decoded, so it's not 100% effective. Also, it may be an accessibility issue - screen readers won't be able to pick up your email address, so it won't be appropriate for all scenarios.